# How to use loops in LISP

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

I have been trying to understand how to use loops in LISP and they still don't really seem to work correctly. I tried using the following code:

```
    (loop for i from 0 to (list-length y)
          (when (eq (values-list (nth i (car y))) 0)
             (return-from checkZero t)))
```

Which should loop through my list checking if my value is equal to 0 or not. If it is equal then it should return from and exit the loop, otherwise it should run until it reaches the list length. Am I thinking about this wrong and if so how do I go about fixing this loop?

(I'm not sure if my actual code works or not yet since I am still dealing with the errors generated by the incorrectly used loop and I can't find many good resources for using loops online)

Comment: Remove the parentheses around `(when (eq ...) (return-from...))` so to have `when (eq ...) (return-from...)` and put a `do` before `(return-from...)`.

Comment: [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/) has a chapter on loop called [LOOP for Black Belts](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/loop-for-black-belts.html). In the book [The land of lisp](http://landoflisp.com/) you have a [practical cheat sheet](http://blog.idorobots.org/media/lolreview/3.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main problem in the loop is the `WHEN`-expression. There are two ways you can write that:

1. Use the loop `WHEN condition DO forms`-clause:

   ```
   (loop for...
         when (eq ...) do (return-from ...))
   ```
2. Use the regular `WHEN`-macro inside a loop `DO`-clause:

   ```
   (loop for...
         do (when (eq ...)
              (return-from ...)))
   ```

There are a few other things to fix in your code.

1. When naming things in Lisp, use dashes between words rather than camelCase (`check-zero` rather than `checkZero`).
2. Use `=` for general numeric comparison, or `ZEROP` to check that a number is zero. `EQ` is used to check if two objects are the same object.
3. You can return from a loop using `RETURN`
4. I'm not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish with the `(VALUES-LIST (NTH ... (CAR ...)))`, but it's not going to work. If you're trying to simply loop over a flat list of values (such as `(1 2 3 4 5 6)`), you should be using the loop `FOR item IN list`-clause.

So now you should have something like:

```
(defun check-zero (list)
  (loop for item in list
        when (zerop item) do (return t)))
```

`LOOP` also has a `THEREIS condition`-clause that you could use:

```
(defun check-zero (list)
  (loop for item in list
        thereis (zerop item)))
```

This return as soon as it finds an item that satisfies `ZEROP`. However, there are easier ways to achieve the same. You could use [`MEMBER`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mem_m.htm) to check if the list contains a zero:

```
(defun check-zero (list)
  (member 0 list :test #'=))

CL-USER> (check-zero '(1 3 4 3 5 7))
NIL
CL-USER> (check-zero '(1 3 4 3 0 5 7))
(0 5 7)
```

This returns a generalized boolean. That is, any value that is not `NIL` is considered true in Common Lisp.

Since there is a predicate function (`ZEROP`) to check if an object is a zero, you could also use [`SOME`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_everyc.htm) or `MEMBER-IF` for this:

```
(some #'zerop '(1 3 4 6 2 0 45 6 7)) ;=> T
(member-if #'zerop '(1 3 4 6 2 0 45 6 7)) ;=> (0 45 6 7)
```

Comment: Slight warning, if the list to check may legitimately contain non-numbers, use `equalp` (if you want 0 and 0.0 to compare equal) or `eql` (if you want both numeric value and numeric type to be the same), since `zerop` should signal an error if the argument is a non-number and `=` is likely to.